# Confused between Kbps and KBps

Tags: performance

I've recently studied in my syllabus that Kb refers to Kilo bits where as KB refers to Kilo Bytes. Also I've studied that Kb refers to speed and KB refers to speed. So according to what I've studied I must be able to download 1 MB of file in 8 Seconds at a speed of 1 Mbps as 1 MB equals 8 Mb. But I can download that file in just 1 Second at a speed of 1 Mbps. How is that possible?

Comment: if you are in a lab there's isolation and more measurement devices could help you find out, but at home, there are more other things may be out of sight that actually affects on speed.

Comment: In general, hardware engineers talk in kbit/ss, Mbits/s, Gbits/s (all with lower case `b`) because each bit is transmitted on a clock measured in kHz, MHz, GHz. In general, software engineers use kB, MB, GB (with capital `B`) because bytes are the smallest addressable unit of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct until the last statement.

You can download a 1 MB file in 8 sec at 1 Mb/s or 1 sec at 1 MB/s.

8 Mb = 1 MB.